# iOS and xcode: how to create a modal segue to a special view only the first time the app is used

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, viewwillappear

I want to make a "terms and conditions" screen that pops up the very first time that app is opened. On this view I would add a button that says "agree," and upon clicking it the code would execute:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

...and would go to the first view of the app.

I am currently using a Tab Bar Controller that has 4 ViewControllers. So basically, I just need to have some method in viewWillAppear on my first ViewController that checks for an NSUserDefault key:value. The first time the app opens, it will be zero. After they click agree, I'll set it to 1 and the bit of code would never execute again.

Can you please offer some code to accomplish the task of routing the view from the firstViewController's view to this alternate view controller upon loading the app?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is what you call 'this alternate view controller'?  Why don't you just use alertview to display a one-time message?

Comment: I have never used alertview... How do I trigger it to occur? Is there anyway to make it so the user can't proceed without clicking "agree" from this alertview? If so, that is my answer I am looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewWillAppear method in your FirstViewController, check NSUserDefaults then present your TermsViewController. After user click agree in TermsViewController, set NSUserDefaults then call

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: That sounds great, but how do I make the FirstViewController start a modal view? The only way I know how is to create a new view in storyboard and control-click-drag a link to it from a button : (  Obviously I want this modal view to appear the first time the app starts without every having the user clicking anything to get there

Comment: control-click-drag a link from FirstViewController to the TermsViewController, make the segue identifier called 'showTerms', then in the FirstViewController call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTerms" sender:nil];

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion. A followup question:  I have a TabBarController, and the first tab bar view links to FirstViewController. In viewDidLoad of my FirstViewController I placed the following code: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myModalSegue" sender:self];    I want to transition to this segue when the first view loads, but I get this error:   Attempt to present <FirstViewController> on <UITabBarController> whose view is not in the window heirarchy!   Any ideas how to fix this??

Comment: It is too early to call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myModalSegue" sender:self] in viewDidLoad, at this time no UI-related things have been prepared, you could call it in viewDidAppear

Comment: So I made the modal segue as specified and named it "termsAndContitions"    Then, in FirstViewController (which is the first view from my TabBarController), I put [self performSegueWIthIdentifier:@"termsAndConditions" sender:self] in the viewDidAppear method.   However, I am still getting this error: Warning: Attempt to present <FirstViewController> and <UITabBarController> whose view is not in the window heirarchy!   Thanks for you patience with me, I am trying my best! Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: So, I had some typos that I caught, and now the app does bring me to the new view with it loads, but then the app crashes with the message:   Receiver <FirstViewController> has no segue with identifier "Terms".    I made the segue in storyboard and named it "Terms" with the tool on the right-sided pane. Am I missing something?

Comment: The app crash on which line? could you paste the code in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29577/discussion-between-jake9115-and-ltebean)

Answer (score 1):

The use of the popover window can get complicated.  Try something like the following if you have little experience with Objective-C.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    if ([termsvalue == 0]) {
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do you agree with the terms of use?"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"- Confirmation -"
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Disagree"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"I agree", nil];
        [alert setTag:100];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView { // Validation
if ([alertView tag] == 100) {
    return YES;
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { // Go
if ([alertView tag] == 100) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // The user has agreed
    }
}
}
```